# Does extending class Queue into class Stack break Liskov Principle?

Tags: design-patterns, stack, queue, solid-principles, liskov-substitution-principle

If I have class `Queue`

```
class Queue {
  pop () {
   return 'Last value of Array'
  }
}
```

...and class `Stack`

```
class Stack extends Queue {
  @Override
  pop () {
   return 'First value of Array'
  }
}
```

Is it breaking the Liskov Substitution Principle? Why?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this violates the LSP because `Stack` is violating the contract of `Queue`. I suspect the comments are inverted in the examples: `Queue` should be FIFO, while `Stack` should be LIFO; but either way, the child and parent have opposite post-conditions for their respective `pop()` methods, so one cannot inherit from the other.

- The post-condition of `pop()` from a `Queue` is that the oldest element is removed.
- The post-condition of `pop()` from a `Stack` is that the newest element is removed.

Clearly these two conditions cannot be satisfied by the same method.

To use Java as an example, [`Queue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Queue.html) has no `pop()` method and is not implemented by [`Stack`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Stack.html).
`Queue` *is* implemented by [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Deque.html), which combines both `Queue` and `Stack` methods, but note how `Deque` is exhaustively documented to define different behaviors for the different sets of methods.